# Is there a way to programmatically set the owner account for a selfhosted n8n instance?

Tags: docker-compose, n8n

We are selfhosting an n8n instance as part of our tech stack and we would like to ensure that the owner setup is completed according to our specification, as we need an n8n API key to integrate into our deployment pipeline, testing and also production setup. This is the docker-compose config, with a custom postgres, so we potentially could add the user as an SQL statement.

```yaml
db:
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
  volumes:
    - ./DOCKER/db/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - ./config/pg:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
n8n:
  image: docker.n8n.io/n8nio/n8n
  ports:
    - "5678:5678"
  environment:
    - DB_TYPE=postgresdb
    - DB_TABLE_PREFIX=n8n
    - DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE=n8n
    - DB_POSTGRESDB_HOST=db
    - DB_POSTGRESDB_PORT=5432
    - DB_POSTGRESDB_USER=postgres
    - DB_POSTGRESDB_PASSWORD=postgres
  volumes:
    - ./DOCKER/n8n/data:/home/node/.n8n
    - ./DOCKER/n8n/files:/files
```

The [n8n documentation](https://docs.n8n.io/hosting/user-management-self-hosted/#step-two-in-app-setup) does mention this step, but no way to automate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no official way to do this. What we now did is to do a `pg_dump` after setting up the root user, even though this isn't an optimal strategy by any means.